# Google Analytics Cookies Appearing in All IIS Log Entries -- GA Not Installed

Tags: iis, cookies, dll, google-analytics

We are running a third-party application on IIS, and the vendor recently gave us a new "diagnostic" DLL to install when we ran into performance problems.

As soon as we installed the DLL and restarted IIS, all of the POSTs and GETs recorded in the IIS (W3SVC1) log began showing Google Analytics cookie info in the URLs -- "_ga=GA1.2.3...".

We have never installed GA for the site, so we assumed it was the new DLL. Reverted to the old DLL and restarted, but GA info persists in IIS logs.

The vendor is giving us a big *shrug*.

Has anyone experienced anything similar, or do you have ideas about how to remedy this situation?

Any insight would be much appreciated.